# Restoring iPhone 5 fails - error 2001?

Tags: itunes, backup, restore, iphone

I've just moved to the States and a family member kindly passed on an old AT&T iPhone 5. The trouble is that it's stuck in a reset loop. When I go into recovery mode and try to restore the phone, iTunes tells me that it can't restore the phone, and gives error 2001.

The background on the phone, as far as I can tell, is this: it started spontaneously shutting down, first every few hours, then progressively more, until it ended up like it is now. They took it to an AT&T store where the representative said it was because the phone's hard drive was full, but I am skeptical that's the real cause.

Is there anything I can do to wipe and restore this iPhone?

Comment: Try Manually restarting your iphone few times and also your Mac.. Also, make sure you are using the latest version of itunes.. Try to restore again it may work..

Comment: Do you need it restored?  The first thing to try would be a [reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252)...  If that works, then you can try restoring it...  If restoring it breaks it, then your best option may be not to restore it, and instead manually install the things you need one by one.

Comment: I guess this is a bit old :)  If you were able to fix it make sure to post an answer, and mark it as accepted.